# simple 500 delay and then re-loop all fadeIn > fadeOuts continuously

Tags: jquery

I have the below simple jQuery chain timed `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`s. These occur initially, on page load. I am simply trying to make these loop continuously, the loop would restart after a `500` delay. I have tried wrapping all this in a single time out function, but that breaks it.

```
  $('.item').delay(500).fadeIn(1500);
  $('.item').delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
  $('.item2').delay(5000).fadeIn(1500);
  $('.item2').delay(500).fadeOut(500);
  $('.item3').delay(9000).fadeIn(1500);
  $('.item4').delay(500).fadeOut(500);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zainabr1/ax63yq6d/1/) is what you are trying to achieve, hope it helps!

#### jQuery:

```
var play = function(){
  $('.item').delay(500).fadeIn(1500);
  $('.item').delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
  $('.item2').delay(5000).fadeIn(1500);
  $('.item2').delay(500).fadeOut(500);
  $('.item3').delay(9000).fadeIn(1500);
  $('.item3').delay(500).fadeOut(500, play);
  }
play();
```

#### HTML:

```
<img class="item" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5d3b6a26fd3e42722d24791603ee8e68/?default=&s=64">
<img class="item1" src="http://7606-presscdn-0-74.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Dubai-Photos-Images-Oicture-Dubai-Landmarks-800x600.jpg">
<img class="item2" src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/0932cfed3e374852a27a09c2ed27061c.png">
<img class="item3" src="https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/32052">
```

#### CSS:

```
.item, .item1, .item2, .item3{
  display:  none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Dude! Perfect, I searched so long for this. Thanks!